# Animate UITextField

Tags: ios, animation, swift, uibutton

I need to make it so that when I click a button, the `UITextField` transforms left onto the `view` from outside the `view`. However, when I execute the following code, the `UITextField` starts off in the middle of the viewcontroller, and then when the button is clicked it transforms left onto the `view` from outside the `view`. How can I make it so that when the view loads initially, it is not seen until the button is clicked, using swift.

```
@IBAction func joinCircleButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let button = sender as UIButton
    joinTextField.frame.origin.x=500
    joinTextField.frame.origin.y=100
    if (button.frame.origin.x - 75>0){
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations:{
            button.frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x - 125, button.frame.origin.y,button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height)
            button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
            self.joinTextField.frame=CGRectMake(self.joinTextField.frame.origin.x - 325, self.joinTextField.frame.origin.y,self.joinTextField.frame.size.width, self.joinTextField.frame.size.height)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the UITextField, or any object that you wish to hide, outside of the view by using a function called:

```
func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
```

This function is called just before the screen is loaded. It gets the sub-views ready but doesn't show them on the screen yet. So this is an opportunity to hide the UITextField from sight like so:

```
 func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){

 // Here is just an EXAMPLE of what I'd do with my text field, you can change this however you wish
 // The point is that I am putting it away so no one can see it at first, and then later it will show
 joinTextField.center = CGPointMake(joinTextField.frame.origin.x-500, joinTextField.frame.origin.y)

}
```

Now the textfield should be hidden when the view loads and then it can be animated later on.I hope this helped.

Comment: It works, thanks. But for some reason, whenever I click on the text field, or any other object, all the animated objects go back to their original position before the animation. How can I stop this behavior.

Comment: Could you describe that a little bit more. Tell me the behavior from beginning to end.

Comment: 1) I click on the button 2) The button moves left, while getting smaller 3) The textfield comes onto the view when the button is clicked 4) Everything is done animating 5) I click on the textfield 6)The button goes back to its original place, but is still the small size, and the text field disappears off of the view

Comment: I've had this happen to my animations before. I cannot explain the phenomena, I believe it has to do with the "viewdidlayoutsubviews". Whenever I make animations I do not use button actions to perform them, but nonetheless. What you can do is use a Boolean and set it to false at first. Place an "if else" statement in the "viewdidlayoutsubviews" where IF the boolean is false then DO the animation otherwise do nothing. Now in your button action place the boolean to True, maybe this will prevent these animation problems. Otherwise, we can do a private chat and I can take a good look at it.

Comment: I believe "viewdidlayoutsubviews" is being called again, or something. I'm not sure, but I've run into situations where things go small and or animations run over and over again.

Comment: I already have an if else statement in the IBAction, to prevent it from animating again. I am not exactly sure of how to do what you said, since I already have an existing if/else statement that mandates wether it animates or not.

Comment: Sorry, I meant place the "if else" inside the "viewdidlayoutsubviews". So "if boolean is false" hide the textfield. And then make the boolean true in the "if else" of your button action, that way "viewdidlayoutsubviews" doesn't get called again presumably. This is a strategy, I can't really explain the phenomena, it happened to me. I believe preventing "viewdidlayousubviews" later on might work.

Comment: Let me make simulate this situation on my computer and then show you if I solved it. Give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68181/discussion-between-somnibyte-and-stevenr).

Comment: I have found a link that I believe may be of some help. I have put it in the chat.